# VeraCrypt after Sierra upgrade: mount_osxfuse: the OSXFUSE file system is not available (255)

Tags: macos, truecrypt

After upgrading my 2015 MBP to Sierra this past weekend, I've had a lot of issues with Samba, Veracrypt, and even VMware Fusion.

VeraCrypt will frequently give the error in the title, `mount_osxfuse: the OSXFUSE file system is not available (255)`, when I attempt to mount a valid encrypted volume. There's nothing wrong with the volume itself, and sometimes if I reboot, I can get VeraCrypt to work properly, but it's certainly touch and go.

OSXFUSE documentation and googling hasn't suggested any fixes for this issue.

I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall OSXFUSE without any luck. Whether it works or not seems random after restarts. Obviously, restarting this often sucks. I restarted on average 3-4 times a year on Yosemite, and I've restarted about a dozen times since upgrading to Sierra dealing with these problems. I'd like to know if there's a permanent fix for this, otherwise I'll be dealing with my encrypted volumes on a Win 10 VM (when VM Fusion works, anyway...yeesh).

Answer (score 11):

The following script from this link fixes the problem:
https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/315

I called this kextclean:

> ```bash
> #!/bin/bash
>
> function status() {
>     kextstat | grep org.virtualbox.kext > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
>     vbox=$((1-$?))
>     kextstat | grep com.github.osxfuse > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
>     fuse=$((1-$?))
> }
>
> status
>
> if [ "$1" == "vbox" ] ; then
>     if [ $vbox == 1 ] ; then
>     echo "Already vbox"
>     else
>         sudo kextunload -b com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfuse
>         sudo kextutil "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox"
>         sudo kextutil "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetAdp.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox"
>         sudo kextutil "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetFlt.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox"
>         sudo kextutil "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxUSB.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox"
>     fi
> elif [ "$1" == "fuse" ] ; then
>     if [ $fuse == 1 ] ; then
>     echo "Already fuse"
>     else
>         sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
>         sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
>         sudo kextutil /Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Extensions/10.12/osxfuse.kext
>     fi
> elif [ "$1" == "status" ] ; then
>     echo "vbox = $vbox"
>     echo "fuse = $fuse"
> else
>     echo "Run $0 <vbox|fuse|status>"
> fi
> ```

Comment: thanks so much for sharing this answer , i've come back to this sh script several times now.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
sudo kextutil /Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Extensions/10.12/osxfuse.kext
```

did fix the problem. TrueCrypt is working again.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I got a "Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed (-603946985)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed (-603946985)}" Error. :-( But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: restarting my Mac got rid of the "mount_osxfuse: the file system is not available (255)" error for me.

I have TrueCrypt 7.1.x but I also installed VeraCrypt 1.21 for continuity. VC requires OSXFUSE 2.5, but I had OSXFUSE <2.5 and so I hit 'upgrade' within System Preferences, to what turned out to be 3.7.1. When I did this, I saw a flavor of the "mount_osxfuse: the file system is not available (255)" error when trying to mount with either VeraCrypt or with TrueCrypt.

The upgrade may be a coincidence, but I had also hit 'Eject' using Finder on my Volume, which I think may have caused the problem.

The intended use is to "Dismount" within TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt instead. Oops. But after restarting, all was well. That's about all the investigating I did.

Answer (score 0):

Update AM 06:34 EST Aug.12 2023

I've met the problem again!

Now, I using the below to fix that:

```
For me the following steps work:

Verify that Terminal has Full Disk Access: System Preference > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access
Run sudo kextunload -b io.macfuse.filesystems.macfuse
```

Also, please refer [this](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/851#issuecomment-1052261655) and [this](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/850).

----*--------*------------*Notices*---------------------------

I meet the same question. I had just upgraded my Mac from `10.12.6` into `12.5.1`, the VeraCrypt worked fine. But when I've accidentally upgraded my Mac from `12.5.1` to `12.6.4`. the VeraCrype got this trouble:

```
Kext load failed ~60349477007
mount_osxfuse: the file system is not available (255)
```

My VeraCrypt version is `VeraCrypt 1.24-Update8`, my macOS is `12.6.4`.

This trouble happened maybe because:

```
1.osxfuse do not installed correctly;
2.osxfuse APP and Kext files are corrupted;
3.osxfuse APP and Kext files are not compatible with the current system version;
4.Insufficient permissions given to osxfuse APP and Kext files.
(If it is confirmed that it has been installed and it is not because of the system version problem, 
it is recommended to check the permission settings of the system)
```

my trouble match the tips`3`;

First, I've just use `brew` to install the latest `osxfuse` via `brew install osxfuse`, but the latest `osxfuse 3.11.2` App is not suitable for `macOS 12.6.4`, so I have to use `macfuse` because `osxfuse` has been succeeded by `macfuse` as of version `4.0.0`, if your CPU was `arm64` or `Apple M1`, you also could choose `macfuse`;

Second, use `brew` to install `macfuse` via command `brew install mmacfuse`, then go to "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General" and see if there is an allow button at the bottom for 'Benjamin Fleischer". If it is there, click on it and then reboot the machine.

Third, if VeraCrypt works, END! if not, then refer [this](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/702#issuecomment-734816831).

Other references:

1.[VeraCrypt does not work on Mac OS 11 Big Sur (SourceForge)](https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/b7cd930cf7/#5033);

2.[kext load failed mount_osxfuse the file system is not available (255) (Chinese Blog)](https://juejin.cn/s/kext%20load%20failed%20mount_osxfuse%20the%20file%20system%20is%20not%20available%20(255));

3.[Why can't I setup an SSHFS share? “OSXFUSE file system is not available” error (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993507/10846570);

4.[OSXFuse & VeraCrypt on Big Sur: OSXFuse seems to be missing on your machine (AskDifferent)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410216/320346);

5.[fuse: failed to mount file system: Undefined error: 0 #27293 (GitHub)](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/27293#issue-192777548)

6.[VeraCrypt  Support for Apple Silicon #702 (GitHub)](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/702).