# OSXFuse & VeraCrypt on Big Sur: OSXFuse seems to be missing on your machine

Tags: macos, filesystem, big-sur

OSXFuse and VeraCrypt were both working fine until the MacOS was updated to MacOS 11.0.1 Big Sur. VeraCrypt no longer opens.

After installing macFuse 4.0.2 (latest at time of posting), I tried to run the installer for VeraCrypt 1.24-Update7 but it gives an error

> OSXFuse seems to be missing on your machine. VeraCrypt requiures OSXFuse 2.5 or above.

How can we get VeraCrypt to work on MacOS Big Sur?

[image]

Comment: It's been 3 months since VeraCrypt was last updated.  It might be something in the install script that is causing it to not recognize the current version of MacFuse.

You might need to contact VeraCrypt to check on their status.

Comment: VeraCrypt works on my BigSur install.  It is using FUSE 3.11.2 and I did have to go through the hoops to get its KEXT installed.

Comment: I had a related, but different issue due to upgrading to `11.0.1`. Thankfully, upgrading to the latest version of _[VeraCrupt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html)_ and _[Fuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/)_ resolved it.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a general problem, see https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/b7cd930cf7/?limit=25#6cb4 and https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/tickets/400/. A new version of VeraCrypt will be required which references the correct path and addresses any other issues related to Big Sur.

Comment: This seems fixed in VeraCrypt now, so updating VeraCrypt solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading macFUSE fixed this for me
https://osxfuse.github.io/2020/11/30/macFUSE-4.0.4.html

Comment: This allowed me to make and open new encrypted containers, but still can't open ones made on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

They fixed the issue over the weekend *as far as the installation of VeraCrypt* but the application still complains about not finding "OSXFuse 2.5 or above" when trying to mount a file.